# What are the minimal privileges for Workligh 6.1.0 DB2 user ID?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

From what I read so far, the WL 6.1 documentation does not much care of this, and it's assumed that database user ID is SYSADM or something like that. Also, I did not see any explicit explanation what privileges the user ID must have.

While SYSADM is fine for development or staging environment, for production is desired to allow the DB user as less as possible, on the other hand I don't wish to get some exceptions related to weak permissions.

Is there any documentation or other source which explicitly mentions/explains what permissions DB2 user ID must have for Worklight 6.1 datasources?

**UPDATE**: My understanding is that for WL *application work* (not install) must be used a separate DB user (mostly for security reason, give as less as possible permissions in production). My question above refers to that "*application*" DB user. It's clear that create tables and schemas activity can do any DB ID, including SYSADM, which is overkill to further work.

I am asking about DB2 user which configured in WAS datasources, once someone else created DBs, schemas and tables.

Answer (score 0):

The DB2 user used to connect to the datasources need not have any special privileges other than to be able to connect to the Worklight databases.  The DB2 user that is used to actually create and initially populate the databases must have SYSADM or SYSCTRL privileges, but these are not needed once the database is set up.

There is more information in the documentation, here:  [Creating the DB2 databases](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_creating_the_db2_databases.html)

Comment: "The DB2 user used to connect to the datasources need not have any special privileges other than to be able to connect to the Worklight databases" - that is false statement, I followed "Creating the DB2 databases" topic from InfoCenter which mentions only "GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE" for wluser, and DB user can not perform even select later.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation defines the privileges required for a user that can create the tables at install time, upgrade the tables for a new Worklight version and use them at runtime.

At runtime, you need, for each table created: SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE. And you need to be able to select a SEQUENCE.

The list of tables and SEQUENCE for Worklight can be found in 
/WorklightServer/databases/create-worklight-db2.sql and create--worklightreports-db2.sql

Comment: "At runtime, you need, for each table created: SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE. And you need to be able to select a SEQUENCE." - this is almost the same what is what I thought. Unfortunately this is not documented and can not be (a) automatically granted at lowest level, and (b) automatically tested if I grant manually. 
Also, for some tables, like WORKLIGHT_VERSION I doubt INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE are required for runtime. Possibly some other tables not require DELETE/UPDATE too.